How can an Android app opt out of the Adaptive Color Tone feature on Samsung phones?

The Adaptive color tone feature is a functionality in the Galaxy S24 series that adjusts screen color and white balance based on ambient brightness. This ensures more natural and comfortable viewing in various environments or lighting conditions

Source: Samsung
This setting is affecting badly the user experience for one application we're developing. We haven't yet found a way to reliably work around this setting without any manual action by users to disable the feature on their phone.
We couldn't find any reference to this feature besides blogs, articles, and youtube videos showing users how to disable it, but nothing related to programmatic opt-out or disabling. We do see that the system responds to different colors being displayed on screen but this is not a reliable mechanism for us to control the feature not kicking in.

It is system wide.
